# How I can Invoke method from UserContol?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

There are many UserControls in my program. Only one user control (default) is visible without entering a password.

When there is a need to see other Users Controls, then the user must enter the password, and after that, another form should immediately appear (the button on which the call was clicked by the user).

For the model, we have 2 user controls.
The first one opens immediately at startup, and to open the second we have to click on its launch button, then a password entry will appear, and (if the password is correct) the required form will be opened.

In the last code display is my problem.

I have `UserLeftPanel` that dispalyed always as a left panel and a `MainForm`(in code `Form1`).
In `LeftUserPanel` are many buttons clicked on, `Form1` will uploud some `UserControl`. 
I don't understand how to get the method from the base class (`Form1`) correctly.

Specifically to my program: 
And if all the user logic of the calls is wrong, I'll be happy to see the right one.

Every UserControl that displayed by clicked on has this construction

```
 private static UserMainPanel_Saved instanse;
    public static UserMainPanel_Saved Instanse
    {
       get
        {
            if(instanse==null)
                instanse =new UserMainPanel_Saved();
            return instanse;
        }
    }
```

Code inside `UserLeftPanel`

```
  public delegate void Handler(object sender,EventArgs e, int control) ;
    public event Handler  ButtonClick;
  protected void ButtonSavedMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int formnumber = 0;          
            this?.ButtonClick(this, e,formnumber);// There are ButtonClick Event in Form1
    }
```

Code inside Form1

```
 private void userLeftPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userLeftPanel1.ButtonClick += UserControl_ButtonClick;
        UserControl_ButtonClick(sender, e, 0);//to display form without password by default
    }
public  void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e,int number)
    {
        UserControl con=null ;
        if (number == 0)
             con = UserMainPanel_Saved.Instanse;
        else
        {               
                if (UserPassword.Password)
                {
                    if (number == 1)
                        con = UserMainDaybook.Instanse;
                }
                else
                {
                    con = UserPassword.Instanse;
                }
        }

        if (!MainPanel.Controls.Contains(con))
        { 
           MainPanel.Controls.Add( con);
           con.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           con.BringToFront();
        }          
        else
        {
           con.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Code inside 'UserPassword'

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Password = true;// In this place will be Some Logic
   //And my idea is to Invoke there UserControl_ButtonClick( ... ) method, but I don't know how
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try separating the event from the method with the logic (notice two different methods: `UserControl_ButtonClick` and `UserControlClick`:

````
public void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, int number)
{
    UserControlClick(number);
}

public void UserControlClick(int number)
{
    UserControl con=null ;
    if (number == 0)
         con = UserMainPanel_Saved.Instanse;
    else
    {               
            if (UserPassword.Password)
            {
                if (number == 1)
                    con = UserMainDaybook.Instanse;
            }
            else
            {
                con = UserPassword.Instanse;
            }
    }

    if (!MainPanel.Controls.Contains(con))
    { 
       MainPanel.Controls.Add( con);
       con.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       con.BringToFront();
    }          
    else
    {
       con.BringToFront();
    }
}```
````

And then in UserPassword:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Password = true;// In this place will be Some Logic
    Form1.Instance.UserControlClick(0);
    //And my idea is to Invoke there UserControl_ButtonClick( ... ) method, but I don't know how
}
```

This way, you won't need to send `object sender, EventArgs e, int number`, you can just send the number.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but it still isn't working.
It wasn't `Instanse` method on `Form1`. It wasn't problem, so I add it.
But if I click on `button1` it's nothing happened.

Comment: @OlegYanytskii tell me, you want to call it from another form, and it's giving you an exception? Or compiling error? I didn't quite understand from your main topic.

Comment: Nothing happens, have you checked on UserControlClick? Put down a breakpoint and tell me.

Comment: I looked what happend from debugger, but i don't understanf why form isn't shown.
All works how was planned!
Is it possible that i must correct my `UserControlCkick` method?

Comment: What happens once ```button1_click``` is fired? does it set con?

Comment: Nothing happened after `button1_click` , but `con` has value!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186223/discussion-between-oleg-yanytskii-and-lucca-ferri).